# Problems with setting up JDeveloper and MAF with android SDK

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

After completing installation of jDeveloper and installing android sdk, I used  [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/onesizedoesntfitall/entry/adf_mobile_deploying_to_android) workaround for jDeveloper to accept it. However upon clicking ok in Preferences->Mobile application frameword -> Android platform this error pops up:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: XPathFactory#newInstance() failed to create an XPathFactory for the default object model: http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom with the XPathFactoryConfigurationException: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryConfigurationException: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory: Provider weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXPathFactory not found`

Answer (score 0):

This is year old question, but I got this today and also find the solution to fix that. just in case someone got same issue later on.

install JDK7 
and modify your /Users/kevin/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/bin/jdev.conf

SetJavaHome /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home

restart your jdeveloper, all done.